# How to ensure 2 injected interfaces are instantiated as the same object instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

Given the following classes

```
public class RWRepository<TEntity, TEntityId> : IRWRepository<TEntity, TEntityId>
```

and

```
internal sealed class EagerLoadingRWRepository<TEntity>
    : RWRepository<TEntity, Guid>
    , IEagerLoadingRWRepository<TEntity>
```

I am registering these in my DI container like this (where `service` is `IServiceCollection`)

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRWRepository<,>), typeof(RWRepository<,>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IEagerLoadingRWRepository<>), typeof(EagerLoadingRWRepository<>));
```

Say I inject both of these into 2 different handlers, both within the same scope. How I can ensure that both handlers will use the same object instance for each injected interface?

I.e. if both interfaces are injected, then both should use the same instance of `EagerLoadingRWRepository`, which inherits from `RWRepository`

Comment: It should be the very same instance in the same scope, that's what the scoped instantiation is about.

Comment: RWRepository and EagerLoadingRWRepository are different classes, so they will never be the same instance. I assume you mean that both IRWRepository and IEagerLoadingRWRepository map to the  same EagerLoadingRWRepository instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be very cumbersome to do with MS.DI (ASP.NET Core's built-in DI Container), because it requires you to make each closed registration explicitly.

For instance:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IEagerLoadingRWRepository<Person>, EagerLoadingRWRepository<Person>>();
services.AddScoped<IRWRepository<Person, Guid>>(
    c => (IRWRepository<Person, Guid>)c.GetRequiredService<IEagerLoadingRWRepository<Person>>());

services.AddScoped<IEagerLoadingRWRepository<Order>, EagerLoadingRWRepository<Order>>();
services.AddScoped<IRWRepository<Order, Guid>>(
    c => (IRWRepository<Order, Guid>)c.GetRequiredService<IEagerLoadingRWRepository<Order>>());

services.AddScoped<IEagerLoadingRWRepository<Shipment>, EagerLoadingRWRepository<Shipment>>();
services.AddScoped<IRWRepository<Shipment, Guid>>(
    c => (IRWRepository<Shipment, Guid>)c.GetRequiredService<IEagerLoadingRWRepository<Shipment>>());
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, I was hoping there may be some other way of achieving it, but I think this will work for my ~12 or so repos

Comment: Hi Bassie, I'm afraid that with MS.DI, there isn't. More mature DI Container might make this easier though.